# Is ESRI metadata standard compatible with GeoNetwork metadata standard?

Tags: metadata, geonetwork, arccatalog

Is ESRI metadata standard compatible with  GeoNetwork metadata standard? If yes how do I update the Geonetwork metadata using Arc-Catalogue 10 Metadata xml?

Comment: There is no such thing as _the GeoNetwork metadata standard_ are you just asking how to load some metadata created by ArcCatalog into GeoNetwork?

Answer (score 2):

You may have an easier time using the FGDC metadata editor which was available at previous releases of ArcGIS Desktop.  There is an add-in that will make this possible.  Here is a link to ESRI's blog post about the topic: http://goo.gl/TlhdS

Answer (score 1):

ESRI metadata bundles together the contents of various metadata standard fields, and they store the lot in their own format.

You can export these contents to standard format (FGDC, ISO, Inspire...) through the Conversion Toolbox (Metadata toolset). 2 tools do the job: the [translator tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Esri_Metadata_Translator/00120000000s000000/) and the [export metadata tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Export_Metadata/00120000000t000000/), detailed below.

To update your metadata from Geonetwork, you will need to translate it first into ESRI format (ArcGIS can only edit ESRI metadata, not standard metadata) using the translator tool. Then edit it, and export it back into the standard used by Geonetwork.

Metadata produced with (or exported from) these ArcGIS tools works well with Geonetwork, as long as you export the metadata from ArcGIS in the standard you use in Geonetwork. We do it in my office with Inspire-compliant metadata, no issues to report.

---

- The translator runs the bare translation between the ESRI format and the standard format. What it does is, essentially, reformat the XML sheet with the tags pertinent to the standard you have chosen.
- The export metadata tool does some processing before running the translator (synchronizes the metadata with the data, notably & some stylesheet updates prior to the export. You can right-click on this model builder tool to view its steps). Depending on your metadata production workflow, it will or will not be useful - just know it is way slower than the translator, of course. A good idea to use this if your workflow includes re-associating the metadata with actual geographical data, to automatically update extents, projection info, etc. May not work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

http://geocat.net/bridge
ref: www.ticheler.net/node/23

lab.usgin.org/groups/etl-debug-blog/create-geonetwork-ogc-harvest-node-wms-or-wfs-getcapabilities-iso-19139-metada

osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/Re-GeoNetwork-users-ArcSDE-harvester-problems-td3388834.html
osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/WMS-Harvest-of-ESRI-Service-td5092576.html

EDIT: http://gispunt.wordpress.com/2009/11/25/creating-a-java-arcgis-server-object-extension-to-access-metadata-through-a-mapservice/

http://www.delicious.com/based2/gis+geonetwork
http://www.delicious.com/based2/bundle:comp.infosystems.gis